# php not taking into account by html

Tags: php, html, css

Hullo :)

I'm sorry if the title is not clear but I don't know how to ask this ( +, I'm not english native :/ )

So ! There, I'm trying to build a website with a php script that spit out a list of members. Everything works fine but the list is not taking into account by the html/css part.

The thing is working fine ( here : http://occlumens.eu/fanlist/membership.php ) but the code is ugly, all tables and it is hell to make something nice in CSS. So ! I decided to work on it and try to just make the whole a bit more interesting with divs.

Here for a visual explanation : http://occlumens.eu/fanlist/membership2.php

As you can see, the list is fine but the box ( html/css ) is not taking the list.
From what I see, my div classes are closing all well but it is as if it wouldn't "read" the php.

If I make a `min-height` in the css, it will only make a box as big as I want, but it still won't take the php into account. So, if the list is smaller or bigger, it won't stretch.

How can I correct that ? Is it because the list is conditional ? ( `if` conditions ) Send help :)
Also, I'm starting to understand php, only starting :) Consequently, I did not code the script.

```
<div class="boxy">
    <h3>Members</h3>
    <p><a href="membership.php?sort=all">Complete list</a> - <a href="membership.php?sort=country">Sorted by country</a></p>
    <p>We have a total of <strong><?php echo PHPFANLIST_MEMBERCOUNT; ?></strong> member(s) from <strong><?php echo $country_count; ?></strong> different countries.</p>

    <?php if (($sort == 'country') && is_null($country)) { // Same sort as above! ?>
    <h2>Sorted by country</h2>
    <div class="membership">

        <div class="one_half">
            <a href="membership.php?sort=country">Country</a>
            <?php foreach ($countries as $country) { ?>
                <p><a href="membership.php?country=<?php echo htmlentities($country['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" title="<?php echo $country['name']; ?>"><?php $fake_member = new Member(); $fake_member->country = $country['name']; if (!DoPluginCalls('show_members_country', true, $fake_member)) { echo htmlentities($country['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); } ?></a></p>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>

        <div class="one_half">
            <a href="membership.php?sort=country&amp;orderby=num">Members</a>
            <?php foreach ($countries as $country) { ?>
                <p><?php echo $country['members']; ?></p>
            <?php } ?>      
        </div>
    </div>

<?php } else { 
    $querystring = '';
    $showmailcol = ShowMail(true, $fanlisting->settings['show_mail']);
?><h2><?php if (!is_null($country)) { $querystring = htmlentities('&country=' . $country, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>Sorted by country: <?php echo htmlentities($country, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); } else {?>All members<?php } ?></h2>
    <div class="membership">

    <div class="one_fifth">
        <?php if ($fanlisting->settings['show_member_id']) { ?>
            <a href="membership.php?sort=all&amp;orderby=id<?php echo $querystring; ?>">ID</a>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php foreach ($members as $member) { ?>
            <?php if ($fanlisting->settings['show_member_id']) { ?>
                <p><?php if (!DoPluginCalls('show_members_id', true, $member)) { echo $member->id; }?></p>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>

    <div class="one_fifth">
        <a href="membership.php?sort=all&amp;orderby=name<?php echo $querystring; ?>">Name</a>
        <?php foreach ($members as $member) { ?>
            <p><?php if (!DoPluginCalls('show_members_name', true, $member)) { echo htmlentities($member->name, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); } ?></p>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>

    <div class="one_fifth">
        <?php if ($showmailcol) { ?>
            <a href="membership.php?sort=all&amp;orderby=mail<?php echo $querystring; ?>">E-mail</a>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php foreach ($members as $member) { ?>
            <?php if ($showmailcol) { ?>
                <p><?php if (!DoPluginCalls('show_members_mail', true, $member)) { if (ShowMail($member->showmail, $fanlisting->settings['show_mail'])) { ?><a href="mailto:<?php echo scramble_email(htmlentities($member->mail, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')); ?>">@</a><?php } else { echo '-'; } } // Plugin Call ?></p>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>

    <div class="one_fifth">
        <?php if ($fanlisting->settings['show_url']) { ?>
            <a href="membership.php?sort=all&amp;orderby=url<?php echo $querystring; ?>">URL</a>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php foreach ($members as $member) { ?>
            <?php if ($fanlisting->settings['show_url']) { ?>
                <p><?php if (!DoPluginCalls('show_members_url', true, $member)) { if (!is_empty($member->url)) { ?><a href="<?php echo htmlentities(handle_site($member->url), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" target="_blank"<?php if ($fanlisting->settings['url_nofollow']) { echo ' rel="nofollow"'; }?>>www</a><?php } else {echo 'www'; } } // Plugin Call ?></p>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>

    <div class="one_fifth">
        <?php if ($fanlisting->settings['ask_country'] && is_null($country)) { ?>
            <a href="membership.php?sort=all&amp;orderby=country">Country</a>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php foreach ($members as $member) { ?>
            <?php if ($fanlisting->settings['ask_country'] && is_null($country)) { ?>
                <p><?php if (!DoPluginCalls('show_members_country', true, $member)) { if (!is_empty($member->country)) { echo htmlentities($member->country, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); } else { echo '-'; } } // Plugin Call ?></p>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>

    <div class="one_fifth">
        <?php if ($fanlisting->settings['show_custom'] && ($fanlisting->settings['custom_field_name'] != '')) { ?>
            <a href="membership.php?sort=all&amp;orderby=custom<?php echo $querystring; ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($fanlisting->settings['custom_field_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php foreach ($members as $member) { ?>
            <?php if ($fanlisting->settings['show_custom'] && ($fanlisting->settings['custom_field_name'] != '')) { ?>
                <p><?php if (!DoPluginCalls('show_members_custom', true, $member)) { if (!is_empty($member->custom)) { echo htmlentities($member->custom, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); } else { echo '-'; } } // Plugin Call ?></p>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Post the code here please.

Comment: `float: left` and `width` attributes.

Comment: Try to put `position: absolute;` in `boxy` then resize to fit the window.

Comment: @Orion `position:absolute;` is taking the whole thing :) but it scrap the responsive :( - I've uploaded if you want to see.

Comment: @bluetie You can set `width` via `media query` to make it reponsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing the php code. By looking at the links though, you could start by setting the table's width to 100% (or whatever width you want). If you cannot figure out how to modify the table tag in php, you can always reference it with css using the parent div like this

```
.boxy table {
     width: 100%;
     /* any other styles here */
}
```

As for the second example, the reason the div doesnt wrap all of the content is because the divs inside it are floating left. If you put something with the style clear:left at the end, right before the closing boxy div, this will make it wrap all the floating content as well.

```
<span style="clear: left>&nbsp;</span>
```

You are probably going to want to stick with a table though since it keeps all of the rows in line.

Comment: Yes ! The clear class ! Aaah, now I understand why this class exist !! Thank you :D
It works like a charm now :)

As for the first example : table is already at 100% but I wanted to get rid of the tables.

Answer (score 1):

It looks better with this:

```
table {
text-align: left;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying not to make tables :) That's the point, to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
table{
text-align:center;
width:100%;
height:auto;
}
```

This will work absolutely fine.